# Jacl script war deploymet

Tags: java, websphere, jacl

I'm trying to deploy war in websphere using jacl script , below is the command i'm using

```
set opts [list -cluster $clusterName -appname $earFileName -contextroot $appContextRoot -installed.ear.destination $destination -MapWebModToVH $virtualHost]

$AdminApp install $earFileLocation  $opts
```

After adding `-MapWebModToVH $virtualHost` parameter i'm getting

**WASX7017E: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String incompatible with java.util.List**

i checked the link http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21428721 for reference.

any help will be appreciated

**updates**

1. `set opts [list -cluster $clusterName -appname $earFileName -contextroot $appContextRoot -installed.ear.destination $destination -MapWebModToVH {$virtualHost}]`

then i get

```
 WASX7017E: Exception received while running file "./CSDeployWar.jacl"; exception information: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String incompatible with java.util.List
```

2  `set opts [list -cluster $clusterName -appname $earFileName -contextroot $appContextRoot -installed.ear.destination $destination {-MapWebModToVH {$virtualHost}}].` 
then i get

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: WASX7122E: Expected "-" not found
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally the below command worked

```
set opts [list -cluster $clusterName -appname $earFileName -contextroot $appContextRoot -installed.ear.destination $destination -usedefaultbindings -defaultbinding.virtual.host $virtualHost]

$AdminApp install $earFileLocation  $opts
```

Answer (score 0):

@upog you passing String as argument, you need to pass it as List. something like this

```
 {-MapWebModToVH {{"JavaMail Sample WebApp" mtcomps.war,WEB-INF/web.xml newVH}}}
```

Look at this page:
http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v5r4/index.jsp?topic=%2Frzatz%2F51%2Fadmin%2Fwsaobjadmapp.htm

Comment: when i changed to set opts [list -cluster $clusterName -appname $earFileName -contextroot $appContextRoot -installed.ear.destination $destination {-MapWebModToVH {$virtualHost}}]. i get java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: WASX7122E: Expected "-"  not found.